# How to get Brand name and Brand Image from Amazon Product Advertising API?

Tags: api, product, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am listing products from amazon to my website. So Basically I need Brand name and Brand image in ItemSearch API call. I need to display brand name as well Brand image on my List page. I am using below API but in that, I am not getting any data for a brand.

API : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Thanks